# Non inverting buck boost transfer function

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, control-system, boost, buck-boost

When considering the compensation of a [non inverting buck boost](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm51772.pdf?ts=1711732711760&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM51772) (single inductor), the datasheet considers to take into account the worst transfer function between the buck transfer function and the boost transfer function:

[image]

Well, the transfer function of the boost and the buck are well documented on the website and it is "easy" to make an appropriate compensation for a buck and a boost converter. Nevertheless, from my point of view, there is an other transfer function with a non inverting buck boost converter. The third one correspond to the "transition region" between the boost and the buck. And in this case, the transfer function is not known and it is probably harder to find than for a boost or a buck. And so it is not easy to me to say that the worst transfer function is the one of the boost.

Here are the waveforms extracted from this [evaluation board](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snvu852a/snvu852a.pdf?ts=1711792696769&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FLM51772EVM-HP) working in three different modes (The output voltage of the NI buck boost is 20 V):

- Boost mode:
  [image]
- Buck mode:
  [image]
- Buck-boost mode:
  [image]

And here are the results of the transient response:

Boost mode:
[image]

Buck mode:
[image]

Buck-boost mode:
[image]

The most important part of the schematic is the following. For more precision, you can find it into the evaluation module user's guide:

[image]

As you can see, the waveforms of the non inverting buck boost, when the converter operates with an input almost equal to the output are largely different from the one of the boost and the ones from the buck. So it seems to me that if we try to get the control to output transfer function of the non inverting buck boost in the transition region, we will firstly need to average the different waveforms. As the waveform are not the same, the transfer function will not be the same. So how can the datasheet can say that the worst case would be the transfer function of the boost?

The next thing that I notice is that the compensation have to be made with the transfer function of the boost converter and so I was expecting a good transient response when the converter was working in boost mode. But it appears according to the above waveforms that the transient response are better when the converter work in buck and in the transition region. Does it means that if the compensation of the boost is correctly done, it will give a better compensation for the buck?

Comment: Please add a schematic and define each waveform in your pictures from relevant nodes on that schematic.

Comment: Also, where did the scope pictures come from? They seem to have a formal title i.e. "Figure 3-20" and you might need to provide a citation link. Additionally, and on further inspection, figure 3-18 is a load current step of 12 amps (or so it seems).

Answer (score 3):

> *As you can see, the waveforms of the non inverting buck boost, when
> the converter operates with an input almost equal to the output are
> largely different from the one of the boost and the ones from the
> buck.*

The [Evaluation module document](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snvu852a/snvu852a.pdf?ts=1711881167067&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) that you likely got your graphs from is misleading you.

This is a better quality version of figure 3-18 (the boost scenario): -

[image]

It's important to look at the detail of the output current because it's actually a 7 amp step change and not a 3 amp change as implied by the title: -

[image]

So, if you took account of this document error, you'd find that the step response for all three scenarios is about the same regarding overshoot.

> So how can the datasheet can say that the worst case would be the
> transfer function of the boost ?

The simple answer is that it is the worst case scenario. Once you take into account that the graph in the document is wrong and, try and recreate what the overshoot would be like in boost mode, it's still a tad worse than in buck mode.

> *Does it means that if the compensation of the boost is correctly done,
> it will give a better compensation for the buck ?*

It's hard to be precise because the boost transient graph isn't directly comparable with the buck transient graph. So, If you fudge the numbers and try and estimate the relative overshoots (should the load transient be identical in both scenarios) then they are about the same with the boost maybe being a tad worse.

> *As you can see, the waveforms of the non inverting buck boost, when
> the converter operates with an input almost equal to the output are
> largely different from the one of the boost and the ones from the
> buck.*

You are trusting the information too much. Just look at these pictures from the document again. Here is my summary and, in short, they appear to have screwed up the results big time (please don't ask me why): -

[image]

You just cannot easily make comparisons between any of these graphs. The info says a 3 amp load change but, clearly that only applies to one of the images.